# SWIG build up configure options

Tags: swig

I have been trying to build up SWIG from sources and install it on my own work area (/home/arriagaa/opt), as support from system administrator is not available. I have done before similar installations of several other libraries (including pcre) successfully.

It seems there is a bug because the libraries (in this case python2 and python3 shared libraries) declared on the configure command can NOT be found - BUT they are there!

It would be possible to have some help such that I could succeed in building up SWIG on my own area, please ?  Please tell me which specific information should I provide you for an effective help from your part.

I am not a software engineer. I am just a user of computers with more than 20 years of experience (on development of retrieval algorithms for meteorological satellite data at www.eumetsat.int, and University of Wisconsin-Madison before), working now back at the Portuguese Met Institute, in Lisbon.

I thank you for the kindness of your attention and help.
Kind regards from
Arlindo Arriaga, PhD Meteorology UW-Madison 1991

Comment: i'd suggest providing more details; the exact command you're running and the error message text would be helpful.

Comment: Please tell me if it is possible (and how) to attach the config.log file. I would try to attach it tomorrow morning in the office (it's late evening in Portugal now). A copy of configure command and options can be just posted. Thanks for the kindness of your help. Arlindo Arriaga

Comment: [swig] @NathanHughes  Tomorrow, in the office (It's late eveing in Portugal now) I will put here the link to my dropbox, where you may find config.log file as well as a copy of my configure options. Thanks for your help. Arlindo Arriaga